# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fun.__callAsync') trying to use setTimeout in a component

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm using React Native and Reanimated and I want an animation to play after 2 seconds.
When a user moves a card, the card should stay at it's new position for 2 seconds, and then move back to it's place.
This is what I have:

```
  const panGesture = useAnimatedGestureHandler<PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent>({
onActive: event => {
  translateX.value = event.translationX;
  if (event.translationX <= 0) {
    // disabling swiping from right to left
    translateX.value = 0;
  }
},
onEnd: event => {
  const shouldStick = translateX.value >= TRANSLATE_X_THRESHOULD;
  if (shouldStick) {
    translateX.value = withTiming(120);
    runOnJS(moveBack)(translateX);
  } else {
    translateX.value = withTiming(0);
  }
},
});
```

I tried using setTimeOut to count 2 seconds, and then update translateX but I get this error:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fun.__callAsync')`

This is moveBack function:

```
const moveBack = (translateX: Animated.SharedValue<number>) => {
console.log("TRANSLATEX: " + translateX);

setTimeout(() => {
  translateX.value = 0;
}, 2000);
}
```

I don't even see the `TRANSLATEX` log, so I guess it won't even get there.
I can't really figure out what's the problem or how to word it so I can find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are declaring the function after you are calling runOnJS, then this error occurs. You need to declare that function before using runOnJS (above that line)

For example:

```
const functionToBeCalled = () => {...do your job here...}

// Then you can call this on runOnJs below: 

runOnJs(functionToBeCalled)()
```

Answer (score 1):

when using runOnJS

const doSomething = () => {
...
} // declare arrow function before runOnJS

runOnJS(doSomething)(arg)

function doSomething(){
...
} // can declare normal function before/after runOnJS coz of hoisting

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was way easier than I thought.
I'm using Reanimated 2.2.0 and there is `withDelay` option to add to the animation and it works great.

This is what I added after `translateX.value = withTiming(120);` (instead of the runOnJs line):

```
translateX.value = withDelay(2000, withTiming(0));
```

So right after setting translateX to 120, it waits 2 seconds, and then setting the value back to 0.